# Shopify cart permalinks: check whether product is in-stock/sold out

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a customised product.liquid template that includes two products in one template, namely: Bikini Top and Bikini Bottom.

The Bikini Bottom is "externally loaded" into the template using its own cart permalink. My question is, when using cart permalinks, how do I check whether the variant is in-stock or sold out and then display a "sold out" notice if needed?

[EDIT] Below is my cart permalink code for reference:

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variantsform">
    <label>Select size</label>
    <select name="id">
        <option value="1189203320">Small</option>
        <option value="1189202416">Medium</option>
        <option value="1189200892">Large</option>
        <option value="1189203928">Extra Large</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="back" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn variantsadd">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

at same that you load the variant with liquid, you have to  check if is available. [Variant manual reference](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/variant#variant-available)

You also can use the [product.first_available_variant](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/product#product-first_available_variant)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! However I don't think this works with cart permalinks right? If it does, how do I make it work? Sorry I'm fairly new to Shopify, I've edited my post above to include the codes I used

Comment: this is cart permalink: http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/cart-page/cart-permalinks

Comment: why are you using code for remote: http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/cart-page/adding-to-the-cart-from-a-remote-website

Comment: I'm doing a customised product.liquid template with two products loaded into it. There are two Add to Cart buttons - one for the Top and one for the Bottom. The cart button for Top is inserted using liquid code but the Bottom one is inserted using the remote cart permalink.

Comment: I'm using this method because I don't know of any other elegant solutions to load 2 products with different SKUs into one product template. Do you happen to know of any other way to do this? Things like these: https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-store/products/can-i-sell-products-together-as-a-bundle-but-track-inventory-seperately are not really what I'm looking for

Comment: easy, use ajax cart https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api , and add all products what you need